Vue 3 with Transition and KeepAlive nested in RouterView
I am migrating my application from Vue 2 to Vue 3 but the KeepAlive does not seem to be working. I tried navigating to the previous page that is included in the KeepAlive but the state was not cached. How can I get it to work?
This is the doc for Transition and KeepAlive but it doesn't work when nested in RouterView: https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-components.html#keepalive
// Vue 2
<transition
  name="fade-transform"
  mode="out-in"
  @after-leave="$root.$emit('trigger-scroll')"
>
  <keep-alive
    :include="[
      'PageOne',
      'PageTwo',
      'PageThree',
    ]"
  >
    <router-view @page-mounted="$emit('page-mounted', this)" />
  </keep-alive>
</transition>

// Vue 3
<router-view
  v-slot="{ Component }"
  @page-mounted="$emit('page-mounted', this)"
>
  <transition
    name="fade-transform"
    mode="out-in"
    @after-leave="$root.$emit('trigger-scroll')"
  >
    <KeepAlive
      :include="[
        'PageOne',
        'PageTwo',
        'PageThree',
      ]"
    >
      <div><component :is="Component" /></div>
    </KeepAlive>
  </transition>
</router-view>


it probably doesn't work if <component> is not the root element wrapped by <KeepAlive> as shown by all the documentation examples. try moving the div outside.

@yoduh Could you provide me with the solution? I'll try it out if possible

I explained the solution which I think is very clear and extremely simple.  Do not use a div in between KeepAlive and component.  Literally <KeepAlive><component /></KeepAlive>.

Here is the example as explained by yoduh  =>
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-v67mab?file=src%2FApp.vue
and here is a crucial part of code:
<router-view
    v-slot="{ Component }"
    @page-mounted="$emit('page-mounted', this)"
  >
    <transition
      name="fade-transform"
      mode="out-in"
      @after-leave="$root.$emit('trigger-scroll')"
    >
      <KeepAlive>
        <component :is="Component" />
      </KeepAlive>
    </transition>
  </router-view>


